# Change device tree on boot

Tags: linux, debian, boot, device-tree

There is a hardware SPI device on my platform, but it doesn't appear in `/dev`.
I read in internet that the hardware description is read during boor from device tree files `(dtb)`.

The problem is that I did search in the filesystem and I was not able to find such a file.

Where does the bootloader search for `*.dtb` files at boot time?

I did log on start-up to see what the board does at boot-up. This is part of the log:

```
Normal Boot
    Hit any key to stop autoboot:  1  0 
    switch to partitions #0, OK
    mmc1(part 0) is current device
    switch to partitions #0, OK
    mmc1(part 0) is current device
    reading /uEnv.txt
    ** Unable to read file /uEnv.txt **
    reading /boot.scr
    ** Unable to read file /boot.scr **
    reading /zImage
    6116584 bytes read in 159 ms (36.7 MiB/s)
    Booting from mmc ...
    fdt_file=imx6ul-var-dart-emmc_wifi.dtb
    reading /imx6ul-var-dart-emmc_wifi.dtb
    30601 bytes read in 21 ms (1.4 MiB/s)
    Kernel image @ 0x82000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x5d54e8 ]
    ## Flattened Device Tree blob at 83000000
       Booting using the fdt blob at 0x83000000
       Using Device Tree in place at 83000000, end 8300a788

    Starting kernel ...
```

And [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L-YMJ4rQuXOkoJtiR6h6z4_uBzeQfd4V/view?usp=sharing) is the entire log.

My goal is to avoid rebuilding the entire kernel. Instead rebuild just the device tree for files for current platform.

Comment: The device tree blob is in the zImage. zImage is a compressed linux kernel and dtb. Not always, you _should_ be able to pass switches to the boot loader to read your modified dtb from another location other than zImage.

Comment: May be able to pass switches to the kernel also to read a different dtb...